# bash - quickly escape any characters string

Tags: bash, shell, grep, escaping, printf

I'm looking for a utility that can quickly escape a string of characters. This task is so useful but i can't found it.

Lets say for an example:

```
hisrmline 'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit$"'
```

If i want to manually escape it, it can be done:

```
'hisrmline '\''h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit$"'\'''
```

But it's time consuming and not efficient. So i found **printf %q**:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$ printf "%q" hisrmline 'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit$"'
hisrmlineh\ \|\ g\ -E\ \"\^\ \[0-9\]\*\ \ exit\$\"[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$ 
[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$
```

**The output is wrong because hisrmlineh was concate together**, so i'm narrow down the strings:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$ printf "%q" hisrmline 'h'
hisrmlineh[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$ 
[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$
```

What i desired was **hisrmline\ \'h\'**

This is especially useful on grep:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$ HISTTIMEFORMAT=""; history|grep -a --color=auto hisrmline\ \'h
 7856  hisrmline 'hisrmline'
 7857  hisrmline 'hisrmline'
 7882  hisrmline 'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit[ ]*$"'
 7883  hisrmline 'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit[ ]*$"'
 7884  hisrmline 'h | g -E "'
 7885  hisrmline 'h | g '
 7886  hisrmline 'h | g'
 7887  hisrmline 'h |'
 7890  hisrmline 'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit$"'
 7891  hisrmline 'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit$"'
 7905  h|g 'hisrmline 'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit$"''
```

And grep -F wouldn't make my life easier when deal with nested single quote, i still have to manually escape the single quote '\'':

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$ HISTTIMEFORMAT=""; history|grep -a --color=auto -F  '[0-9]*  exit$"'\'''
 7889  h|g -aF 'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit$"'
 7890  hisrmline 'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit$"'
 7891  hisrmline 'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit$"'
 7905  h|g 'hisrmline 'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit$"''
 7911  h|g 'hisrmline 'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit$"''
 7912  h|g 'hisrmline '"'"'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit$"'"'"'
```

Is there any easier way or any existing utility to escape list of any characters string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you quote the command line properly then `printf` should work e.g.:

```
printf "%q\n" "hisrmline 'h'"
hisrmline\ \'h\'
```

Or:

```
printf "%q\n" "hisrmline 'h | g -E \"^ [0-9]*  exit$\"'"
hisrmline\ \'h\ \|\ g\ -E\ \"\^\ \[0-9\]\*\ \ exit\$\"\'
```

---

**EDIT:** You're probably looking for this kind of escaping:

```
IFS= read -r str<<"EOF"
hisrmline 'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit$"'
EOF

printf "%q\n" "$str"
hisrmline\ \'h\ \|\ g\ -E\ \"\^\ \[0-9\]\*\ \ exit\$\"\'
```

**[UPDATE by @林果皞]**

To whom might be interested, EOF have to quoted to prevent expansion, as noted by @bize:

EOF without quoted:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai Downloads]$ IFS= read -r str<<EOF
> target='h | g -E -i -e "^[ ]+[0-9]+  .*[|&; ]+g[ ]" -e "^[ ]+[0-9]+  .*[|&; ]+g$"'; history|grep -aF "$target"; echo ${#target}
> EOF
[xiaobai@xiaobai Downloads]$ printf "%q\n" "$str"
target=\'h\ \|\ g\ -E\ -i\ -e\ \"\^\[\ \]+\[0-9\]+\ \ .\*\[\|\&\;\ \]+g\[\ \]\"\ -e\ \"\^\[\ \]+\[0-9\]+\ \ .\*\[\|\&\;\ \]+g\$\"\'\;\ history\|grep\ -aF\ \"h\ \|\ g\ -E\ -i\ -e\ \"\^\[\ \]+\[0-9\]+\ \ .\*\[\|\&\;\ \]+g\[\ \]\"\ -e\ \"\^\[\ \]+\[0-9\]+\ \ .\*\[\|\&\;\ \]+g\$\"\"\;\ echo\ 73
[xiaobai@xiaobai Downloads]$
```

"EOF" quoted:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai Downloads]$ IFS= read -r str<<"EOF"
> target='h | g -E -i -e "^[ ]+[0-9]+  .*[|&; ]+g[ ]" -e "^[ ]+[0-9]+  .*[|&; ]+g$"'; history|grep -aF "$target"; echo ${#target}
> EOF
[xiaobai@xiaobai Downloads]$ printf "%q\n" "$str"
target=\'h\ \|\ g\ -E\ -i\ -e\ \"\^\[\ \]+\[0-9\]+\ \ .\*\[\|\&\;\ \]+g\[\ \]\"\ -e\ \"\^\[\ \]+\[0-9\]+\ \ .\*\[\|\&\;\ \]+g\$\"\'\;\ history\|grep\ -aF\ \"\$target\"\;\ echo\ \$\{#target\}
[xiaobai@xiaobai Downloads]$
```

Correct behaviour only when supplied from the output of quoted "EOF":

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai Downloads]$ h|g -F target=\'h\ \|\ g\ -E\ -i\ -e\ \"\^\[\ \]+\[0-9\]+\ \ .\*\[\|\&\;\ \]+g\[\ \]\"\ -e\ \"\^\[\ \]+\[0-9\]+\ \ .\*\[\|\&\;\ \]+g\$\"\'\;\ history\|grep\ -aF\ \"\$target\"\;\ echo\ \$\{#target\}
 7721  target='h | g -E -i -e "^[ ]+[0-9]+  .*[|&; ]+g[ ]" -e "^[ ]+[0-9]+  .*[|&; ]+g$"'; history|grep -aF "$target"; echo ${#target}
 7725  target='h | g -E -i -e "^[ ]+[0-9]+  .*[|&; ]+g[ ]" -e "^[ ]+[0-9]+  .*[|&; ]+g$"'; history|grep -aF "$target"; echo ${#target}
 7726  atarget='h | g -E -i -e "^[ ]+[0-9]+  .*[|&; ]+g[ ]" -e "^[ ]+[0-9]+  .*[|&; ]+g$"'; history|grep -aF "$target"; echo ${#target}
 8297  target='h | g -E -i -e "^[ ]+[0-9]+  .*[|&; ]+g[ ]" -e "^[ ]+[0-9]+  .*[|&; ]+g$"'; history|grep -aF "$target"; echo ${#target}
 8320  target='h | g -E -i -e "^[ ]+[0-9]+  .*[|&; ]+g[ ]" -e "^[ ]+[0-9]+  .*[|&; ]+g$"'; history|grep -aF "$target"; echo ${#target}
```

*h is aliased to `export HISTTIMEFORMAT=""; history
*g is aliased to`grep -a --color=auto

Direct use of `$ h|g -F "$str"` is working too.

When deal with unicode, i have to assign LC_ALL= to empty(i.e LC_ALL="en_US.utf8") before query(history, ls..etc) the source string. Then i have to switch it to LC_ALL=C to make printf %q working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is looking for an easier/quickly/faster way without have to navigate the string and manually add \" one by one. I'm surprised because i can't even to found this kind of utility tool on Google. With just copy the strings and paste to convert it, without have to manually add slash \ for every occurrence of double quote "

Comment: No you don't really have to escape each `"` by `\"` manually, see my updated answer. You can read the whole string in a variable `str` and then simply use: `printf "%q\n" "$str"`

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

In comments you told that you copy the lines from history and want to reinsert them in a shell command. In `bash` there is [*history expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) to access parts of the history or modify it. Probably this is already what you want.

Otherwise you could create a little command to display the history escaped:

```
IFS=$'\n' history | while read line ; do printf "%q\n" "$line"; done
```

You can copy lines from that output and insert them into a shell string. You may additionally pipe this to less if your `$HISTSIZE` is large.

If you need this command more often you may create a script file out of it or create a function in the `.bashrc`

---

**Original Answer**

Let's say want to use the `'` as the string delimiter, you can use the following `bash` expression:

```
string="hisrmline 'h | g -E \"^ [0-9]*  exit$\"'"
echo "${string//\'/\\\'}"
```

Now you can use the string in bash. If you want to use it in `grep` or other programs which use regular expression, you would need to escape further characters. However grep supports the option `-F`. If you pass it, patterns are handled as fixed strings, not as regular expressions.

Comment: I know grep -F, but my question is looking a easier/quickly/faster way without have to navigate the string and manually add ' " ' " ' OR ' \' ' one by one. I'm looking for `printf %q list_of_strings` but as you can see on my question it doesn't works when dealing with single quote.

Comment: Where are the strings coming from?

Comment: for my case, it's come from my history

Comment: ya, i've write a functions put inside ~/.bashrc to remove history by exact match. I just have to type `$hisrmline` and paste the argument `hisrmline 'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit[ ]*$"'` and it will remove this line correctly. But i have to manually edit the arguement to make it escape.

Comment: Have you tried [history interaction commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html)? Probably this what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, i tried your `IFS=$'\n' history...` approach but it failed when deal with the history which contains backslash(it should make it \\\), e.g. `h| g -F target=\'h\ \|\ g\ -E\ -i\ -e\ \"\^\[\ \]+\[0-9\]+\ \ .\*\[\|\&\;\ \]+g\[\ \]\"\ -e\ \"\^\[\ \]+\[0-9\]+\ \ .\*\[\|\&\;\ \]+g\$\"\'\;\ history\|grep\ -aF\ \"h\ \|\ g\ -E\ -i\ -e\ \"\^\[\ \]+\[0-9\]+\ \ .\*\[\|\&\;\ \]+g\[\ \]\"\ -e\ \"\^\[\ \]+\[0-9\]+\ \ .\*\[\|\&\;\ \]+g\$\"\"\;\ echo\ 73`

Answer (score 1):

A kiss aproach:

```
printf "%q" "$(cat <<"_up_to_here_"
hisrmline 'h | g -E "^ [0-9]*  exit$"'
_up_to_here_
)"
```

Anything betwen `"_up_to_here_"` and `_up_to_here_` will be correctly quoted.

PLEASE NOTE:
  The first `_up_to_here_` is quoted to prevent expansion of any $variable in the next line or line(S).

COMMENT: the use of `cat` is intended to keep the command simple, any attemp to correctly convert to `read` will require extensive knowledge: Not a KISS aproach.

Comment: Thanks you so much, "quoted to prevent expansion" is so important as companion to @anubhava answer, EOF should be quoted. Still i can only accept one answer :) For who might interest when deal with unicode, i have to assign LC_ALL= to empty before query(history, ls..etc) the source string. Then i have to switch it to LC_ALL=C to make printf %q working correctly.